# Dynamic array with struct that contains a union in C

Tags: c, struct, unions, dynamic-arrays

I'm kind of new to C, so please bear with me.
I have a struct that contains union of other structs with variable sizes like this:

```
typedef struct _obj_struct {
    struct_type type;
    union obj {
        struct1 s1;
        struct2 s2;
        struct3 s3;
    } s_obj;
} obj_struct;

typedef struct _t_struct {
    unsigned int number_of_obj;
    obj_struct* objs;
    other_struct os;
    unsigned int loop;
} t_struct;
```

The struct_type is the type of the struct we use in the union.
How do I go through all elements in the objs?
Is this the right way to do this:

```
struct1 s1;
struct2 s2;
struct3 s3;

for (j=0; j<t_struct.number_of_obj; j++)
{
    switch (t_struct.obj[j].type) {
        case STRUCT1:
            s1 = t_struct.objs[j].s_obj.s1;
            break;
        case STRUCT2:
            s2 = t_struct.objs[j].s_obj.s2;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: very confusing: you have to defined `STRUCT1` and `STRUCT2` then you can use

Comment: You'd probably need to have a case for STRUCT3 using `s3 = t_struct.obj[j].s_obj.s3;`, presumably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need the copy of each structure, use pointers instead:

```
struct1 *s1;
// ...
s1 = &t_struct.objs[j].s_obj.s1;
```

Please note, that you have to specify an element of the union as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `t_struct.obj[j].s_obj` is the union, not the actual structure. You have to use `t_struct.obj[j].s_obj.s1` etc.

Comment: Yes, I misplaced that when I copied the code. Already fixed, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While accessing a member of union contained inside a struct, the general syntax is

```
structVariable.unionVariable.memberName
```

The way you're accessing is fine if you just add the member name at the end. So the correct version would be:

```
switch (t_struct.objs[j].type) {
    case STRUCT1:
        s1 = t_struct.objs[j].s_obj.s1;
        break;
    case STRUCT2:
        s2 = t_struct.objs[j].s_obj.s2;
        break;
}
```